# How to initialize TColumnEh

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

It's a simple question.
How to initialize variable Column to make the following statement.

```
procedure TfmSomeForm.grdSomeGridDblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Column: TColumnEh;
  IsSomething: Boolean;
begin
  inherited;   
  //Initialize Column

  IsSomething := False;
  if Column.FieldName = 'SOMETHING' then
    IsSomething := True;
```

Initialize Column that way

```
 Column := grdSomeGrid.Columns.FindColumnByName('SOMETHING');
```

makes no sense and probably will lead to exception 
**or** i have to do it here

```
procedure TfmSomeForm.grdSomeGridCellClick(Column: TColumnEh);
begin
  inherited;
  FIsSomething := False;
  if Column.FieldName = 'SOMETHING' then
    FIsSomething := True;
end;
```

The problem is that i need this flag **onDblClick** and i don't want to make it global.

Comment: What problem are you anticipating with `Column := grdSomeGrid.Columns.FindColumnByName('SOMETHING')`?  You should check for `Column` being Nil, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say which datatype your `grdSomeGrid` is.  However, with an ordinary TDBGrid, what you seem to want to do is straightforward to do in the DblClick event itself.

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ACol : Integer;
  Pt : TPoint;
  CellValue : String;
begin
  { pick up the mouse cursor pos and convert to DBGrid's internal  coordinates }
  Pt.X := Mouse.CursorPos.X;
  Pt.Y := Mouse.CursorPos.Y;
  Pt := DBGrid1.ScreenToClient(Pt);

 { find the column number of the double-clicked column}
  ACol := DBGrid1.MouseCoord(Pt.X, Pt.Y).X - 1;

  if DBGrid1.Columns[ACol].FieldName = 'SOMETHING' then
    { do what you want}
end;
```

**Update**:  Victoria helpfully mentioned `SelectedIndex`, which is another way to get the current column, but I always manage to forget it because its name doesn't include `Column` and there isn't a direct counterpart for the row (because row operations are based around bookmarks, rather than row indexes).

So, I do it the way I have because it reminds me how to get the active column and row indexes, and it's easy to write a free-standing function which gets both at the same time, like this:

```
type
  TRowCol = record
    Row,
    Col : Integer;
  end;

function GetRowCol(Grid : TDBGrid) : TRowCol;
var
  Pt : TPoint;
begin
  { pick up the mouse cursor pos and convert to DBGrid's internal  coordinates }
  Pt.X := Mouse.CursorPos.X;
  Pt.Y := Mouse.CursorPos.Y;
  Pt := Grid.ScreenToClient(Pt);

  Result.Row := Grid.MouseCoord(Pt.X, Pt.Y).Y;
  Result.Col := Grid.MouseCoord(Pt.X, Pt.Y).X;

  { adjust Col value to account for whether the grid has a row indicator }
  if dgIndicator in Grid.Options then
    Dec(Result.Col);

end;
```

Comment: It's a custom grid, but it is pretty much the same. I take care of Column indexes OnCellClick with global variable  FColumnIndex := Column.Index;  but i will try this way it looks more elegant. Excuse me, my english is far from perfect. Thank you.

Comment: For `TDBGrid` may help also [SelectedIndex](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TCustomDBGrid.SelectedIndex). For [TDBGridEh](http://www.ehlib.com/online-help/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=DBGridEh_TDBGridEh.html) haven't found similar.

Comment: @Victoria:  Indeed.  Btw congratulations on your 1k+